# Wonder's hood end, or is it wonderhood's end?

Tags: possessives, suffixes

-hood is the suffix  indicating a place or condition, i.e. childhood, neighborhood, etc.  At times I have considered the title of the Arthur Clarke novel CHILDHOOD'S END and have wondered if CHILD'S HOOD END might have been the better choice?  Please entertain me with your conjecture or proof.

Comment: This is nonsensical.

Comment: "Childhood" is a single word.

Comment: You run up against the fact that this is English, not Random-language-I-made-up-because-I-wanted-to-change-English. You are of course perfectly free to speak RLIMUBIWTCE; but you risk being misunderstood and thought strange if you do so.

Comment: "Nonsensical"?  Is that a conjecture or a proof?

Comment: The end in question is the end of childhood, not the end of a child.

Comment: The end of childhood not the end of the child.  That was very insightful.  It was the very point I pondered when I asked myself the question to begin with, i.e. just what was ending?  On the other hand, -hood is only a suffix so child's hood end is illogical.  Now I know better.  :>)

Answer (score 1):

As a word modifier, a suffix isn't detached when the plurality of a word changes.  Traditionally hood is a suffix, not a separate word. Although recently "hood" has been used as a shortening of "neighborhood", that's not a condition, which is what -hood in childhood means. There are words that could be used, by I agree with Mr. Clarke.